# Why is zero conductivity media called lossless?

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, plane-wave

Doesn't zero conductivity mean infinite resistance which would lead to infinite loss.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PhysicsSE! Please, consider adding context to your question. Where did you find this definition of "lossless"? Infinite loss of what?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific context. If we were talking about driving an electric current through metal, then the *losses* would be the energy dissipated by this electric current. This I think is the premise behind the question. However, if we talk about interaction with light, then a conducting media will incur losses, while a media with zero conductivity - i.e. an insulator, will allow lossless propagation of the light.

Answer (score 1):

One can show that the attenuation of an E&M wave as it propagates in a material depends basically on the ratio $\sigma/\epsilon \omega$.

The attenuation factor, usually denoted by $\alpha$, has a [somewhat complicated expression](https://www.sjsu.edu/people/raymond.kwok/docs/ee140/Lossy_Medium.pdf) but, in the case for instance of a low-loss dielectric, $\alpha\approx \frac{\sigma}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\epsilon}}$.  Thus, when $\sigma\to 0$, the attenuation factor $\alpha\to 0$ and the wave does not *loose* any of its energy in inducing currents (*i.e.* moving electrons) in the material: since $\sigma=0$, the resistivity $\rho$ is infinite and so it would take an infinite amount of energy to move electrons in that material.